# Select query including a link table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a problem with a select query

I need to `select coid,model,km,year` for all the vehicles which have `AC` and `MP3`.

I wrote this SQL:

```
select distinct 
    vehicle.vehid, model, km, year
from 
    vehicle, models, extras, veh_extras
where 
    models.modid = vehicle.modid 
    and vehicle.vehid = veh_extras.vehid
    and extras.extraid = veh_extras.extraid 
    and (descr = 'AC' or descr = 'mp3')
```

but I think it's wrong. `Extras.desc` is the column which take the description of the extra.

[schema link](http://prntscr.com/7296v7)

Comment: What is coid? That column isn't in the tables you posted. You also might take a look at this article and consider using the ANSI-92 style joins. They are much cleaner and less prone to error. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: But you need both extras (AND) or at least one of them (OR)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT v.vehid, m.model, v.km, v.year
FROM vehicle v 
JOIN model m ON v.modid = m.modid
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                FROM extras e 
                JOIN veh_extras ve ON e.id = ve.extraid
                WHERE ve.vehid = v.vehid
                AND e.descr = 'AC'
             )
AND EXISTS (    SELECT 'a'
                FROM extras e 
                JOIN veh_extras ve ON e.id = ve.extraid
                WHERE ve.vehid = v.vehid
                AND e.descr = 'mp3'
             )
```

This is probably not the best way... but if you need to search for more extras simply add another EXISTS condition

Comment: This will find rows where either AC or mp3. It isn't quite what the OP is looking for because they want only those that have both options.

Comment: Is not clear from his question,, I asked for it in the comment area but he didn't answer yet

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want vehicles that have both AC and MP3, then one option would be to join to the `veh_extras` table multiple times:

```
select distinct v.vehid, m.model
from vehicle v
  join models m on m.modid = v.modid
  join veh_extras ve on v.vehid = ve.vehid
  join extras e on ve.extraid = e.extraid and e.descr = 'AC'
  join veh_extras ve2 on v.vehid = ve2.vehid
  join extras e2 on ve2.extraid = e2.extraid and e2.descr = 'MP3'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d36f/4)

---

Another option would be to use case aggregation:

```
select v.vehid, m.model
from vehicle v
  join models m on m.modid = v.modid
  join veh_extras ve on v.vehid = ve.vehid
  join extras e on ve.extraid = e.extraid 
group by v.vehid, m.model
having sum(case when e.descr = 'AC' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when e.descr = 'MP3' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

- [More Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d36f/5)

BTW -- I left out some of the remedial columns -- easy to add those back...

Answer (score 1):

> but i think its wrong.

Even if it works then also it is not the recommended way.

Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS. Instead try to use JOINS like this:

```
select distinct v.vehid,model,km,year
    from vehicle v inner join models m on v.modid = m.modid 
                 inner join veh_extras ve on ve.vehid = v.vehid
                 inner join extras e on e.extraid = ve.extraid          
        where  
            e.descr='AC' or e.descr='mp3'
```

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted. I would suggest using aliases but otherwise this is FAR better than the old style join.

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted but also `vehicle.vehid = models.modid ` needs to be `vehicle.modid = models.modid`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would suspect the OP is looking for vehicles with both AC and MP3, not either.  A little difficult to say for sure though.

Comment: @JChao:- Indeed. Updated that!

Comment: @sgeddes:- Yes that seems to be a point. Waiting for OP to respond.